# WebdriverIO tests don't run accordingly against dockerized Selenium server

Tags: selenium, docker, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I have a simple WebdriverIO project with a few test cases. I run everything "locally" (no `CI` variable declared according my `wdio.conf.js` settings) with `browserName: "chrome"` in *headless* mode, and `Mocha` test runner.

Now, I'm trying to run exactly the same test cases against a Selenium server (started via Docker), but all tests cases fail with this little error message: `Timeout of 15000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

> If I go to the Selenium Web console I can see the sessions being created and deleted, so the configuration should be OK.

```
// wdio.conf.js
const cfg = require("config");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const source = { };

if (process.env.CI) { // ...if running on a CI/CD environment
  source.hostname = "localhost";
  source.maxInstances = 5;
  source.path = "/wd/hub";
  source.port = 4444;

  source.services = ["selenium-standalone"];
} else {
  source.filesToWatch = [];
}

exports.config = Object.assign({}, {
  runner: "local",

  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: cfg.get("baseUrl"),
  coloredLogs: true,
  exclude: [
    // "test/spec/**.spec.ts",
  ],
  filesToWatch: [],
  hostname: "localhost",
  logLevel: "warn", // trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
  maxInstances: 1,
  outputDir: `${__dirname}/logs/`,
  path: "/",
  port: 9515,
  specs: ["./test/**/*",],
  sync: true,
  waitforTimeout: 25000,

  framework: "mocha",
  specFileRetries: 0,
  mochaOpts: {
    require: ["tsconfig-paths/register"],
    timeout: 15000,
    ui: "bdd",
  },

  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: "chrome",
      maxInstances: 5,
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        args: [
          "--disable-gpu",
          "--headless",
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--test-type",
        ],
      },
    },
  ],

  reporters: ["spec",],
  services: ["chromedriver",],

  before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    require("ts-node").register({ files: true, transpileOnly: true });
  },

  // ...Cucumber specific hooks
}, source);
```

Moreover, I disabled all test cases and put something simple like this:

```
browser.url(`https://duckduckgo.com/`);
$("#search_form_input_homepage").setValue("webdriverio");
$("#search_button_homepage").click();
const expected: string = "WebdriverIO · Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js";
expect($("div#r1-0 h2.result__title a.result__a").getText()).to.contain(expected);
```

...and still, the same error message >:(

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** — define/set proxy settings at the container level.

---

OK, it was a silly detail: we use a corporate proxy.

My initial thoughts was to try setting the proxy info (at the browser level) in `wdio.conf.js`:

```
capabilities: [
  {
    browserName: "chrome",
    maxInstances: 5,
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
      args: [
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--headless",
        // "--no-sandbox",
        "--test-type",
        // "--window-size=1024x768",
      ],
    },
    proxy: {
      httpProxy: "http://corporate.proxy:9080",
      noProxy: ["127.0.0.1", "localhost", ".domain.tld",],
      proxyType: "manual",
      sslProxy: "http://corporate.proxy:9080",
    },
  },
],
```

...but that didn't work, so I ended up setting that at container level (in the Docker Compose file):

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  chrome:
    container_name: standalone-chrome
    environment:
      - CHROME_VERSION=76.0.3809   # ...make sure this is in sync with the chromedriver version in package.json
      - HTTPS_PROXY=http://corporate.proxy:9080
      - HTTP_PROXY=http://corporate.proxy:9080
      - NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost,.domain.tld
      - START_XVFB=false
    healthcheck:
      interval: 15s
      retries: 3
      timeout: 30s
      test: "/opt/bin/check-grid.sh --host chrome --port 4444"
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-selenium
    networks:
      - global-network
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

networks:
  global-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: selenium-network
```

Then I can run the tests against that dockerized "standalone" Chrome instance, or in the CI/CD pipeline via: `CI=docker npm run test` (mapped in `package.json` like: `"scripts": { "test": "wdio" }`).

Hope this helps somebody in the future...